# "A New Outlook on Shannon’s Information Measures" abstract clarification

Tags: measure-theory, information-theory

I was curious about the paper [A New Outlook on Shannon’s Information Measures](https://csc.ucdavis.edu/%7Echaos/courses/poci/Readings/Yeung.IEEETransInfo1991.pdf) by Yeung. However, I don't really understand the abstract

> Let. $X_i,i = 1,. . .,n$, be discrete random variables, and
> $\tilde{X}_i$ be a set variable corresponding to $X_i$. Define the
> universal set to be $\bigcup_{i=1}^n\tilde{X}_i$ and let $S$ be the
> $\sigma$-field generated by $\{\tilde{X}_i,i = 1,. . . ,n\}$

what does

> $\tilde{X}_i$ be a set variable corresponding to $X_i$

mean?

and what is the $\sigma$-field generated by $\{\tilde{X}_i,i = 1,. . . ,n\}$?

Comment: Is it the smallest $\sigma$ algebra on which $X_i$ is measurable?

Comment: When $n=2$ or $n=3$, draw a Venn diagram with $n$ circles, as you did in school.  This divides the plane into disjoint regions.  Discard the region at infinity.  The remaining regions are the atoms of the sigma field they generate.  If $n=2$ there are 3 remaining regions, the sigma field has $8$ elements in it.  You can name the regions $X\setminus Y,$ $X\cap Y$, $Y\setminus X$, and give them Shannonesue names, according to the recipe given in the paper.

Comment: If the discrete random variable $X_j$ takes values in a set $E_j$, It seems to that the author refers to $\{X^{-1}_j(A): A\subset E_j\}$. Each element of such family is a "set variable".

Comment: I found a [related math overflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/416857/what-is-the-set-variable-corresponding-to-a-random-variable) and a [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_theory_and_measure_theory#Entropy_as_a_%22measure%22) but it is still not very clear to me what is going on